# "ls" is giving a "Permission denied" error even though it worked?

Tags: linux, permissions

I have a directory that have the `r` permission bit:

```
dr-------- 3 robert robert 4096 2017-12-17 03:47 dir
```

This directory has two files and one directory:

```
file 1.txt  file 2.txt  subdir
```

When I run the command `ls dir` (from the `robert` account), I get an error alongside the content of the directory:

```
ls: cannot access dir/file 1.txt: Permission denied
ls: cannot access dir/file 2.txt: Permission denied
ls: cannot access dir/subdir: Permission denied
file 1.txt  file 2.txt  subdir
```

Why does `ls` display an error even though it is able to display the contents of directory without any problem?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`ls` calls `readdir()` (or `getdents()`) on the directory itself, which amounts to "reading" the directory. I think some Unixes implement this as actual calls to `read()`, as if the directory was a file. That works, since you have read permission to the directory, but it only gives the names of the files.

In addition to that, `ls` often wants to find the types of the files (to show different types with different colors, or to put the trailing slashes and asterisks etc. with `ls -F`). But finding the type generally requires calling `stat()` on the files themselves, and that requires access (`+x`) permission to the directory, in the same way actually opening the files would require. And you don't have that.

Comment: For quite some time now the on-disk format of a directory isn't any simple list of names, and read(3) of directories is forbidden.

Comment: @vonbrand, the kernel could still generate the results of the `read()` as a list of names. Perhaps only for backwards compatibility, but anyway. But I'm not sure, I seem to recall seeing that on some BSD, but I don't have any current ones to check on.